# How to show new image in Visual Composer in frontend wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Visual Composer I have added new filed in back-end in using this code

```
array(
    "type" => "attach_images",
    "heading" => __("Flag Upload", "js_composer"),
    "param_name" => "flag_image_id",
    "value" => "",
    "description" => ""
),
```

it is worrying fine in back-end but now I am stuck how to show this filed in front-end?

I have attached image for more understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below will get your image information of the flag you just need to insert this into your output html box

```
//Image information for any pictures.
       // Gets url of the image
       $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $flag_image_id );
       // Gets the Image Alt
       $image_alt = get_post_meta($flag_image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
       // Gets the image name with exstention
       $image_filename = basename ( get_attached_file( $flag_image_id ) );
       // Gets the image name without exstention
       $image_title = get_the_title( $flag_image_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function designas_partners() {
    // Title
    vc_map(
        array(
            'name' => __( 'Clients' ),
            'base' => 'designas_partners_content',
            'category' => __( 'Easy Component' ),
            'params' => array(



                array(
                "type"        => "attach_images",
                "heading"     => esc_html__( "Add Clients Images", "appcastle-core" ),
                "description" => esc_html__( "Add Clients Images", "appcastle-core" ),
                "param_name"  => "screenshots",
                "value"       => "",
                ),



            )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'designas_partners' );

function designas_partners_content_function( $atts, $content ) {

$gallery = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'screenshots'      =>  'screenshots',
    ), $atts );

 $image_ids = explode(',',$gallery['screenshots']);
 $return = '
    <div class="clients">';
    foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ){
    $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'company_logo' );
    $return .='<div class="images"><img src="'.$images[0].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'"></div>';
    $images++;
    }
    $return .='</div>';
return $return;
}   


add_shortcode( 'designas_partners_content', 'designas_partners_content_function' )
```